# How to add transparent notch to a DIV with CSS only?

Tags: css

I want be able to style a DIV with CSS to accomplish the result below. The white noth should be transparent. There are a lot of tutorials available for doing the same, but with the arrow outside the DIV instead of inside the DIV (with borders).

Can somebody help me further please?

[image]

Comment: Can we see the code that you tried?

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but then I end up with a lot of javascript. Is there no solution possible with CSS only?

Comment: @RajenderJoshi No css example yet, because I don't know how to start. Maybe I can add 2 DIVS to the left side of the DIV box. The top side of the noth can be the bottom border of the first DIV. The second DIV the same but then for the bottom side of the notch.